# MYSQL Calculate date difference in digital time format

Tags: mysql, sql, time

In one of the table I have 2 columns name **date1** and **date2** having **datetime** data type

I am calculating difference between these two dates using `timediff(date2,date1)`. Now suppose

`date1=2018-04-05 13:10:00
date2=2018-04-05 14:40:00`

then the difference between these two dates will be `01:30:00`

MY MAIN QUESTION IS how to convert this `H:i:s` time to digital time format like `01:30:00=1.5` or `01:45:00=1.75`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `time_to_sec` to convert to seconds. Then divide by 3600 (60 seconds per minute; 60 minutes per hour) to get to hours:

```
select time_to_sec(timediff(timestamp '2018-04-05 14:40:00', 
                            timestamp '2018-04-05 13:10:00')) / 60 / 60;
```

By the way, you can also use `timestampdiff` instead of `timediff` to get seconds right away:

```
select timestampdiff(second, timestamp '2018-04-05 13:10:00',
                             timestamp '2018-04-05 14:40:00') / 3600;
```

Answer (score 0):

select hour(timediff(date1, date2)) + minute(timediff(date1, date2))/60 + second(timediff(date1, date2))/60